# Is there a way to create an aws custom layer from Local nodejs modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, aws-lambda-layers

I created some custom aws layers and they work, but all of this layers have dependencies from npm repositories, what I want to do or to know (because I searched a lot but nothing found) is if this scenarios are possible:

- I have a **fooModule** without dependencies
- Then inside a nodejs folder I use `npm init - y` and then `npm i /path/to/fooModule`

My file structure at the end

```
nodejs
--package.json (1)
--node_modules
  --fooModule
    --index.js
    --package.json (2)
```

- package.json (1) generated with npm init is

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "fooModule": "file:/path/to/fooModule"
  }
}
```

- I make a zip and I get this message in my lambda after upload my zip

`Error: Cannot find module 'fooModule'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/src/handlers/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js`

Questions:

- These messages are because of my fooModule reference ?
- Do I need to publish my module so I'll be able to create my layer ?
- What if I have 2 modules, fooModule and barModule and foo depends on bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I achieved what I want by using `npm pack` in my fooModule which generates fooModule-1.0.0.tgz file.

After that I just use `npm i /path/to/fooModule/fooModule-1.0.0.tgz` to import my packaged module inside my nodejs folder and create my aws custom layer.

So, the answers:

These messages are because of my fooModule reference ?
**Yep, if you want to do the same use the`npm pack` command.**

Do I need to publish my module so I'll be able to create my layer ?
**Yes, but if you dont want to publish your module with `npm publish` it's also possible work with local modules**

What if I have 2 modules, fooModule and barModule and foo depends on bar ?
**No matter how manny modules you have, just use npm pack to create the local package correctly**

And that's it, if someone has better approach, please comment. :D